# How to know that we have to use exclamation mark or full stop after an imperative sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

How to know that I we have to use exclamation mark or full stop after an imperative sentence? For example- Surrender./!. In this sentence, l have to use full stop or an exclamation mark? Also in this sentence-Stop. /! Give examples..

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the ELU. This site encourages users to make their own research before they ask a question. Have you done any? It is not clear why you have doubts about such a matter, and I am not sur it is specific to English language only.

Comment: This is a matter of style, not something with a right or wrong answer. Some people like exclamation marks and others hate them, and their appropriateness depends on the context: in a comic book or crime novel, they're fine, but in a formal letter they're less so. To ask a question here, you need to be more specific about what you're writing and what you intend, and even after that it may not have a right or wrong answer.

Comment: Not all imperatives are exclaimed just because they are commands. For example, a friend might say to another: “*Come here*” with a light, brooding tone and a gentle nod; whereas a mother might say to a disobedient child, “***Come here!***”. It depends on the intonation and context as well; not just merely a stylistic choice. To say “..imperatives must have an exclamation mark following it because it is a command..” is a prescriptive view; one that is a misconstrued generalisation.

Comment: Thanks for your answers and l apologize for my mistakes